# How to prevent local connection timeout when using SQL Azure Migration Wizard

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, database-migration, bcp

I am trying to export data from my sql server database using the [Sql Azure Migration Wizard](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/). I am intermittently hitting a problem with timeouts:

> Unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server
>   connection

Is it possible to increase the timeout used by the migration wizard? Or can I change the default timeout in sql server?

NB I am getting this problem on my own server, not when I try to connect to Azure.

**Edit**
At the bottom of the Result Summary tab the wizard prints a summary of the bcp output commands used to export data. I copied these into a command window and they ran. Still getting timeouts reported. So it appears to be a limitation to do with bcp. I am using Sql Server 2008 R2 and bcp version 10.50.1600.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things that I would try.

Use the IP and port number instead of the hostname to connect. 10.10.0.1,1433 for example.

Use the -l switch to increase the login timeout.  More info about bcp switches here, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568446%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: The -l switch isn't available in the version of bcp I have. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802(v=sql.105).aspx . Do you know if I can use a newer version of bcp with sql server 2008 R2?

Comment: The IP address appears to have done the trick - I was using "localhost"